# problem with my cocoaPod library HFCardCollectionViewLayout

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I found an amazing library that makes same as i want, a cardHolder:

[image: screenshot of the card holder]

but i cant understand even how to use it. I integrated it in my project. Created an CollectionView and succeeded from HFCardCollectionViewLayout. Now i have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsOqv.jpg) : )

my code looks like

```
{
  import UIKit
  import HFCardCollectionViewLayout

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cardsCollectionView: HFCardCollectionViewLayout!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

And i cant understand how to decorate this collectionView, because i didnt work with such libraries and HFCardCollectionViewLayout doesnt have DataSource and DelegateFlowLayout? Shoud i use CollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and DataSorce?. What should i do? Any information should be useful.

Comment: the problem is https://cocoapods.org/pods/HFCardCollectionViewLayout there is no answer should i succedeed my own UICollectionView to HFCardCollectionView? It said use only HFCardCollectionViewLayout.

Comment: Take a look at the sample project in that pod.   It does a decent job of showing how to implement it.

Comment: Did you checked the source https://github.com/hfrahmann/HFCardCollectionViewLayout and check the Sample App?

Comment: how can I find sample app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you don't have a `dataSource` and a `delegateFlowLayout` because `HFCardCollectionViewLayoutDelegate` implements a `UICollectionViewDelegate`, and `HFCardCollectionViewLayout` implements `UICollectionViewLayout` and `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

You can check the [Readme here](https://github.com/hfrahmann/HFCardCollectionViewLayout/blob/master/README.md)

HFCardCollectionViewLayout has a pretty straightforward implementation example. To run it:

1) Clone the pod repository on your computer:

```
git clone https://github.com/hfrahmann/HFCardCollectionViewLayout
```

2) Open the `HFCardCollectionViewLayoutExample` folder, then open the `HFCardCollectionViewLayoutExample.xcworkspace` file;

3) Run the project. The implementation is in `ExampleViewController.swift` and `ExampleCollectionViewCell.swift`. You can also see the source code [here](https://github.com/hfrahmann/HFCardCollectionViewLayout/tree/master/HFCardCollectionViewLayoutExample/HFCardCollectionViewLayoutExample).

[image]

Comment: OMG! SO MUCH THX!